# Como traçar rotas ao gmaps com shapes/polígonos

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Precisarei manipular um mapa ( de preferência gmaps ) contendo as mesorregiões de cada estado. Encontrei um [mapa de mesorregiões](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=ztql1O_xwz6g.kVg0q9HY4ysM&hl=en_US) criados a partir do gmaps, porém ele não me permite interações como criar rotas, etc.

Como unir as duas características em um único mapa?

Comment: Se você conseguir extrair este mapa e entender como ele funciona. Você poderia calcular a rota normalmente e depois "plotar" neste estilo de mapa. Apenas um palpite...

Comment: Posta o que já fez. É javascript?

Comment: Sim, javascript. @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você pretende traçar rotas como sugestão de um caminho de um lugar a outro, seja de carro, de ônibus, ou outro meio de transporte, não deve usar shapes/polígonos e sim a api directions service, que já está disponível no seu script por estar referenciando o google maps. 
Com essa api você pode passar duas posições em latidude e longitude ou passando os nomes dos lugares(nesse caso, especificando em que idioma os nomes estão) e ela vai retornar uma lista de pontos LatLng com o caminho sugerido. Você também pode passar até oito pontos intermediários por onde quer que o caminho passe.
Aí com essa lista você desenha uma polyline no maps, é fácil.
[Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Já se você quer utilizar os shapes e polígonos pra traçar um desenho por cima das regiões, vai ter que recuperar várias posições de fronteiras e montar os shapes na mão mesmo. Tem algumas respostas interessantes pra isso
[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3)

Answer (score 0):

veja se isso pode ajudar te:

```
//-- Classe responsável em buscar os pontos de rota (Curva a Curva) do Google
private class getRoute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    //-- Método de Execução da Task
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... parametro)
    {           
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet("https://maps.google.com/maps?output=json&saddr="+_start+"&daddr="+_end);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpclient.execute(http);
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            if(entity != null)
            {
                InputStream instream = null;
                try
                {
                    instream = entity.getContent();
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String resultString = converterStreamEmString(instream);
                try
                {
                    instream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String regex = "points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"";
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(resultString);
                if(m.find())
                {
                    obterPontos(m.group(1));
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    //-- Converte o binario para double
    private void obterPontos(String str)
    {
        _lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
        _lon = new ArrayList<Double>();

        str = str.replace("\\\\", "\\");

        int index = 0, len = str.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = str.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

           _lat.add(lat*1E-5);

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = str.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            _lon.add(lng*1E-5);

            // Usando a lat e lng acima, preencha o objeto que representa 
            // um ponto no mapa (varia de acordo com a API de mapas)
            // e adicione a sua coleção de pontos
        }
    }
}

    //-- Converte o Stream recebido do servidor Google para String
    private String converterStreamEmString(InputStream is)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int a;
        try
        {
            while ((a = is.read()) != -1)
            { 
                buffer.write(a);
            }
            buffer.close();

        return new String(buffer.toByteArray());

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```